# My parent class __init__() has three parameters and I want to use only two of its parameters?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, super

I have this class and I want to inherit only two of its init parameters to the subclass

> Note
> Here I am not having any concern about the Employee and Manager but I am asking in general about the syntax i.e., Is the **init**() method in my subclass is correct? or I need to take the exact number of parameters taken in the super class

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,Ename,Eid,Esalary):
        self.Ename = Ename
        self.Eid = Eid
        self.Esalary = Esalary

    def emp_details(self):
        print(f"The employee name is {self.Ename}")

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self,Ename,Esalary):
        super().__init__(Ename,Esalary)



e1 = Employee("TestE","A12E",12000)
mgr_1 = Manager("TestM",100000)
```

But it is throwing an error
TypeError: `__init__()` missing 1 required positional argument: 'Esalary'

and How to inherit only two of its `__init()__` parameters

Comment: You've written `Employee` so that to make `Employee` you must provide an `Eid`. A `Manager` is an `Employee`, so the `Eid` has to come from somewhere.

Comment: Why wouldn't a manager have an id? If it doesn't, it probably shouldn't inherit from `Employee`, or the id isn't really a property of all employees, but rather a different subclass of `Employee`.

Comment: You must fill in something for the third parameter in `super().__init__(...)`. Maybe "None" is enough.

Comment: As a general rule, you can *add* things to a subclass, but you cannot *remove* things.

Comment: @khelwood Imagine that a manager don't have any Eid  In general case how to inherit only two of its parameters

Comment: @chepner Do you have any documentation for this rule As a general rule, you can add things to a subclass, but you cannot remove things

Comment: You can fill in None in place of the `Eid` if that's what you want. But it doesn't seem like you've thought through your models clearly.

Comment: @VarunKumar It's implied by the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); allowing a `Manager` to have no id makes it unsuitable to use where an `Employee` is expected.

Comment: If only some employees have ids, then you might need two intermediate subclasses of `Employee`, with `id` being a property of one and `Manager` being a subclass of the other.

Comment: @chepner Here I am not having any issues with Employee and Manager But I am asking in general case i.e.,syntax

Comment: It's a design issue, not specific to any one language.

Comment: @chepner ok that's clear

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a parameter in the constructor of your Employee. In constructor of Employe, you have three arguments and below you are just giving two so be sure to give it three.

Comment: Suppose I want to have only two parameters in the subclass , Then what to do?

Comment: Probably you can have a default value in your constructor like this `def __init__(self,Ename,Eid=0,Esalary) ` so even if the argument is missing you can still have a value. The second option is to set the third argument in subclass to "None"

Comment: You can't give a default value to `Eid` because it's followed by the non-default argument `Esalary`.

Answer (score 2):

As Manager is subclass of Employee, Manager is also an Employee... and with that logic Manager should also have Eid.

If you question is only for Educational purpose, you must call super().**init** with 3 parameters.

If you question is for some real project, and you are very much sure that Manager should not have Eid, then reconsider changing class design (i.e. remove class inheritance).

Comment: Is there any way to use the init method in the sub class with only two parameters??

Answer (score 1):

Something like below is technically possible, but meaningless.

```
   class Manager(Employee):
       def __init__(self,Ename,Esalary):
           super().__init__(Ename,None,Esalary)
```

However, something as below might have some meaning (but not a good practice).

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,Ename,designation,Esalary):
        self.Ename = Ename
        self.designation = designation
        self.Esalary = Esalary

    def emp_details(self):
        print(f"The employee name is {self.Ename}")


class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self,Ename,Esalary):
        super().__init__(Ename,'Manager',Esalary)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the 'None' value to your third parameter. Do something like this :

```
class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self,Ename,Esalary):
        self.Eid = None
        super().__init__(Ename,Eid,Esalary)
```

Comment: This would give you a `NameError` because you're referencing a variable `Eid` that you have not created. `self.Eid` is different from `Eid`.

Answer (score 1):

### **Try this:**

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,Ename,Eid,Esalary):
        self.Ename = Ename
        self.Eid = Eid
        self.Esalary = Esalary

    def emp_details(self):
        print(f"The employee name is {self.Ename}")

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self,Ename,Esalary):
        Eid=""
        super().__init__(Ename,Eid,Esalary)


e1 = Employee("TestE","A12E",12000)
mgr_1 = Manager("TestM",100000)
mgr_1.emp_details()
```